# Does there exist an invertible matrix with 1,-1 and 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an invertible matrix which has exactly one $1$ and exactly one $-1$ in every row and all other entry are zero? For example, $$  
 \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 0&0 \\
0 & 0& 1 &-1\\
0 &1 & -1&0\\
1&0& -1&0\end{array} \right).
$$
Note: the above matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Hint: What is the sum of the columns?

Comment: If $x$ is the vector with all components $1$, what is $Ax$?

Comment: sum of the column is not important

Comment: thank Daniel Fischer . I got my answer

Comment: @ali darij grinberg wanted to tell you that the columns of such matrix are linearly dependent hence it is impossible to be invertible.

Comment: You realize that if $x$ is the vector with all 1, then $Ax$ is the sum of the columns in each entry...?

Comment: Yes is it, Alan!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373600/why-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-with-the-sum-of-each-rows-elements-equal-0-is-0

Answer (score 2):

For any matrix $A$ made that way we have that $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is an eigenvector associated with a zero eigenvalue, so it is not possible that $A$ is invertible. On the other hand, if we take $A$ as the difference between the identity matrix and a circulant matrix, the eigenvalues are given by:
$$ 1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i k}{n}\right),\qquad k=1,2,\ldots,n $$
so the rank of $A$ is allowed to be $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4$ is the application associated to this matrix, then its kernel is given by four equations of the form $A=B$ where $A$ and $B$ are two different elements from $\{x,y,z,w\}$.

If two of these equations are the same, then it is clear that the matrix is singular. Otherwise, the set of equations can be rendered as a graph with $4$ vertices (the variables) and $4$ edges (the equations). It is easy to see that such a graph is connected, that is, any vector with the four components equal is in the kernel. Thus, $f$ is not an isomorphism and the matrix is singular.

Comment: A vector with all components equal is *always* in the kernel.  The graph being connected is only relevant to the kernel having exact dimension $1$.