# Linear Algebra - properties of positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a positive semi-definite, symmetric matrix, of order $3\times 3$ satisfying:
$$
\Sigma_{j=1}^{3}  a_{ij}=0
$$ 
for $i=1,2,3$ (i.e.- the sum of each row is zero).

Prove:
$a_{ij}\leq 0, \quad \forall i\neq j$.

I know that $det(A)\geq 0$, and that the determinant of every principal submatrix is also nonnegative. I also know that the trace of every principal submatrix is nonnegative, which implies that the diagonal elements are nonnegative. But I wasn't able to use these properties in order to deduce the required claim.

Will you please help me with this?

Thank you very much

Comment: The determinant should be exactly zero, actually http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373600/why-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-with-the-sum-of-each-rows-elements-equal-0-is-0

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the comment. Have you got any idea about the proof of the claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure?

Define the matrix $A$ as
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&1\\-2&4&-2\\1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly, the matrix $A$ is symmetric and the sum of the coefficients of each of its rows is nil. Moreover, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ (double eigenvalue), and $6$, hence $A$ is positive semi-definite.

Yet, $a_{13}=1>0$.

Comment: You are right. I was absolutely certain that my claim is right, but obviously it was wrong... 
Thank you very much !!!